# How do I sign into jetpack joyride on the same account but on different device?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I have gone into profile but still can't figure it out.I just got a new phone and downloaded jetpack joyride but couldn't figure out how to use the same account on different devices.

Comment: I can't start all my progress on jetpack joyride over

Comment: The game account links with your email. Providing your using the same email, the phone will automatically use the same account

Answer (score -1):

I think you can make your old account log in to facebook or google and repeat the same thing to your new account.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, Jetpack Joyride does not support any cloud saves/backups.

Comment: As of version 1.8 there is cloud saving with a Halfbrick account.